# Action Script 3.0 Error 1105 : Target of assignment must be a reference value

Tags: actionscript-3, zooming

So, I have a frame containing two images and a paragraph text. I want to make only the two images zoomable by using the mouse scroll. But, for some reason the paragraphs are also zoomed in. I have tried to code it. Can you guys fix where it went wrong?
Error 1105 lies in the event.target.width(image1a) += zoomamountmlfr1;

```
var deltavarimage1amlfr1:int;
var deltavarimage2amlfr1:int;
var image1a : MovieClip = new MovieClip;
var image2a : MovieClip = new MovieClip;
var zoomamountmlfr1:int = 10;

addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_WHEEL, wheelimage1a2amlfr1);
function wheelimage1a2amlfr1(event:MouseEvent):void {
deltavarimage1amlfr1 = event.delta;
deltavarimage2amlfr1 = event.delta;
if (deltavarimage1amlfr1 > 0) {
    event.target.width(image1a) += zoomamountmlfr1;
    event.target.height(image1a) += zoomamountmlfr1;
}
else if(deltavarimage2amlfr1 > 0) {
    event.target.width(image2a) += zoomamountmlfr1;
    event.target.height(image2a) += zoomamountmlfr1;
}
else if(deltavarimage1amlfr1 < 0){
    event.target.width(image1a) -= zoomamountmlfr1;
    event.target.height(image1a) -= zoomamountmlfr1;
}
else if(deltavarimage2amlfr1 < 0){
    event.target.width(image2a) -= zoomamountmlfr1;
    event.target.height(image2a) -= zoomamountmlfr1;
}
```

}

Comment: Width is a property of a **Number** type. For example, if it is 895.5 (you are free to pick any other number), your line translates to **895.5(image1a) += zoomsomething**. I hope you understand what's wrong with it.

Comment: @Sarah When you say `event.target.width(image1a)` are you trying to specifically target `image1a` and `image2a` with those brackets?